# Split comma seperated values and concatenate with other row values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query

I have a table like below

```
|   ID     |    Numbers       |  
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   6      |  3245,78765,1234,43566  |  
|   7      |  8245,88093,8326,92365  |
```

I want a query that can produce the below

```
|     Results         |
------------------------- 
|   3245_sub_6       | 
|   78765_sub_6       |
|   1234_sub_6       |
|   43566_sub_6      |
|   8245_sub_7       |
|   8326_sub_7      |
|   92365_sub_7     |
```

I am trying to split values in the above table into something like below;
like concat(splited value,'*','sub','*',id) something like that.

Can't seem to get how to write this query. Been beating myself up for days. Please Help

Comment: It is usually unwise to store multiple values in a commalist instead of in separate rows, usually involving a separate table.  Heed this advice next time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,',',num),',',-1),'_sub_',id) results
FROM `table`, (SELECT 1 num UNION ALL
               SELECT 2     UNION ALL
               SELECT 3     UNION ALL
               SELECT 4) nums
```

The numbers count in `nums` subquery is to be equal or greater than max values count in CSV field. If values count is fixed and numbers count is equal to it, you may remove DISTINCT.

If MySQL version is 8+, the numbers pseudotable can be generated in CTE.

Comment: Superb answer. Works like a Charm.... Interesting.. I have been at this for days. Am not sure I would have been able to write this query like forever without your help.....